# Add foreign key in Yii migrations

Tags: php, mysql, yii, foreign-keys, database-migration

I try to add foreign key to table, but when I run migration I getting this error:

```
 General error: 1005 Can't create table 'chooseone.#sql-49a_49'
```

Its strange because `chooseone` is the name of my database. Here is how I try to add FK:

```
$this->addForeignKey('FK_user_profile', 'tbl_profile', 'user_id', 'tbl_user', 'id', 'CASCADE', 'CASCADE');
```

So what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you adding the foreign keys **after** adding the table? Ensure the tables `tbl_profile` and `tbl_user` exist and are spelled right. In addition, give it a try without the prefix `tbl_`.

Comment: @Martijn Hols , when I run yiic migrate first creates tbl_user table, then create tbl_profile, when creates tbl_profile I create FK at once. the code copied form my old project, where migrations work properly with table prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this issue. I change my definition of id column in tbl_user:

```
'id'       => 'INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY',
```

to

```
'id'       => 'pk',
```

and all works properly.

Comment: Aha, so you had a column type mismatch. [`'pk' => 'int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY',`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/7b0281b4f0ee6fd1e0e64f0dedd571ccce9536fd/framework/db/schema/mysql/CMysqlSchema.php#L25), which differs from your old code in that it's a signed int by default. Not sure if the length in INT(10) instead of INT(11) matters for the relationship.